# Question on Subdivision?

Tags: lists, exam

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage[paperheight=10.5in,paperwidth=8.27in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=1in,
top=0.7in,bottom=1in,headsep=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt}   %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
 }
\runningheader{\footnotesize Mathematics}
{\footnotesize Mathematics --- Differential Geometry}
{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize Student's name:}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ continues
on the next page\ldots}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize End of exam}{\footnotesize Please go        on to the next page\ldots}}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
%==============================================================
\begin{document}

%% \thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[l]{.1\textwidth}%
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1.5\textwidth]{vit1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{.68\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
{\large \bfseries School of Advanced Sciences  \par
\Large VIT UNIVERSITY CHENNAI CAMPUS \\[2pt]
\small Modern Physics {(\small Code: PHY101)}  \par}
%  \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[l]{.160\textwidth}%
\noindent
{Slot: C1}\\
{\footnotesize {7 Oct 2014}}
\end{minipage}}
\par
\noindent
Dr. Arun Kumar Sarma   \hfill \hfill        Dr. Sanjit Das \\
\noindent
\uline{Time: 1.5 hour   \hfill \normalsize\emph{\bf{CAT II}} \hfill        Maximum Marks: 50}
\begin{questions}

\pointsinrightmargin
\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints
%\marginpointname{mark}
\pointpoints{mark}{marks}
\pointformat{\boldmath\themarginpoints}
\bracketedpoints
\question[06]
\label{Q:EinAB}
Find relation between spontaneous emmission and absorption
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(a)]
\end{enumerate}
 \droppoints
 \question[10]
 \label{Q:zbus}
 Prove that necessary conditions for the curve $u = u(t), v = v(t)$ on a surface $\vec(r) = \vec(r)(u,v)$ to be geodesic is that \begin{equation}U \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{v}} - V    \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{u}}\end{equation}
where
$$ U = \frac{d}{dt} \Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{u}}\Big) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{2T}\frac{dT}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{u}}$$
$$ V = \frac{d}{dt} \Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial    \dot{v}}\Big) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial v} = \frac{1}{2T}\frac{dT}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{v}}$$
\droppoints
\question[8]
\label{Q:zbus}
For 
$$
x = a(3u - u^{3}),\qquad y = 3au^{2},\qquad z = a(3u + u^{3})
$$
show that $$\uptau = k  =  \frac{1}{3a(1+u^{2})^{2}}$$
\droppoints
\question[8]
\label{Q:zbus}
 A curve is uniquely determined except as the position in space, when its curvature and            torsion are given functions of its arc length.
\droppoints
\question[8]
\label{Q:zbus}
Show that there exists an infinite family of involutes for a  gives curve.
\droppoints
\newpage
\question[08]
\label{Q:ybus}
Give short answers of the following questions.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Define Helicoids?
\item Define spherical indicatrix?
\item Define the intrinsic equation?
\item Write the statement of existence theorem for space curve?
\item The normal curvature $k_{n}$ is equal to the what?
\item Prove that $L = -n_{1} \cdot r_{1}$ and $N = -n_{2}    \cdot r_{2}$?
\item Define the geodesic?
\item Write down the equation of tangent plane?
\item If equation of the circle is $x^{2} + y^{2} = a^{2}$ then the parametric equations            of circles are \xblackout{forty     two}?
\end{enumerate}
\end{questions}
\begin{center}
\rule{.5\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

In this format of question paper I was trying to improvise number subdivision from the beginning. What I mean by this is to start as 1) (a) ...in the next line (b)... something like that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It is not clear to me what you are asking. Could you state more clearly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're describing the `part` system.  Refer to the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) documentation for a full explanation, but here's the example from it:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
Why is there air?

\question
What if there were no air?

\begin{parts}
\part
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.

\part
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}

\question
\begin{parts}
\part
Define the universe.  Give three examples.

\part
If the universe were to end, how would you know?
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ricci1729 I'm glad I could help.  Would you consider marking this answer as accepted, then?  Along with being the preferred way to say 'thanks' around here, it also keeps the site neat and tidy for future visitors :)

Comment: I have one problem when compiling. It is showing some error with \droppoint. Also I was looking how to put the number corresponds to each question on the right hand side. Please help me in this matter.

Comment: @ricci1729 Can you post a *minimal* working example?

Comment: :Please see this link from writelatex. https://www.writelatex.com/1513106msrhsm#/3764734/    I have two questions.. 1) I am putting the marks for each part by \hfill. 2) When I use \droppoint it shows error. So is there any way to put marks but without using \hfill ??

Comment: It's `\droppoints`, not `\droppoint`.  Also, you'll want to move it to *after* the question text.  Note that `\droppoints` will drop the points into the margin, not just before.  As for not using `\hfill`, just add point values to the questions and issue `\droppoints`.  (I'm sure there is a way to automate the `\droppoints` addition, but I'm at work and can't really work on it right now.